# Generalized Inverse Gamma Distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution

Mathematica has a four-parameter generalized inverse gamma distribution:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseGammaDistribution.html

and gives its PDF on that page too. Has anyone implemented the density, distribution, quantile, and sampling-from functions for that in R?

I did make a quick start (the PDF is just the equations on that page translated into R) but if its done already I'll not bother with implementing the CDF and the quantile function.

Does a general function for computing the CDF (by integration of PDF) and the Quantile (by inversion of the CDF) of any distribution given the PDF exist?

[Note this is *not* the generalized inverse Gaussian]

Note also the 'Properties and Relations' dropdown on the Mathematica page, which seems to imply its not a special case or generalisation of anything (apart from the inverse gamma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started a package to implement this:

https://github.com/barryrowlingson/geninvgamma

Its only using simple inversion and integration of the density, so nothing clever. Currently random samples from the distribution are done by generating a U(0,1) and getting the quantile,  which isn't very efficient or very accurate it seems..

Anyway, its a start.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ghyp/vignettes/Generalized_Hyperbolic_Distribution.pdf) (Appendix C2), the inverse gamma distribution is a special case of the generalized hyperbolic distribution which is implemented by the `ghyp` package.

Comment: Yeah, but the _generalized_ inverse gamma has another couple of parameters which I don't see how they would fit into this framework. Several different parameterisations of the same distribution never help with clarity though...

Comment: Well, you could just curry those parameters to their fixed values, possibly by just wrapping the functions from `ghyp` in a new set of d/q/p/r functions. Alternatively you could use the functions in that package as a starting point and analytically/programatically remove the parameters that are fixed.

Comment: The problem isn't removing parameters that are fixed, its adding in new parameters that are variable...

Comment: Maybe it would help if we knew which parameterization you needed?

Comment: @Spacedman Ah, sorry. I was being dense and missed the point you were making, despite it being in italics. I see now why this would not work.

Comment: @JasonMorgan any parameterisation of the generalized inverse gamma is as good as any other. I'd prefer the one used by Mathematica for consistency. The parameterisation problem is when you have a bunch of related distributions expressed with different parameterisations. My simple brain gets confused.